# Plotting slices (time index) of two or more columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I regularly aggregate stock timeseries price data and find myself needing to plot slices of said data.

If my dataframe (df) contains the column (or columns) I want to plot I simply use

```
df.loc['DATE'].plot
```

But let's say I hypothetically have this data set (df) Panda

```
Index    A B C D
01-2010  1 2 3 4
02-2010  4 2 3 4
03-2010  2 2 5 5
04-2010  4 4 3 4
05-2010  6 2 4 2
06-2010  3 2 3 4
```

And I wanted to plot df['A'] and df['C'] for 03-2010 onward...
Normally I would reduce the df into a df I want to plot such as:

```
df=df.loc['03-2010':]
df=df.drop(['B','D'],axis=1)
df.plot()
```

1. Is there a better way to do this in one or two lines--particular without dropping all the columns I don't need (if I have a ton of columns)? Maybe passing specific column slices?
2. Let's say the two (for now) columns have different values, is there a way to plot slices of them with a secondary Y axis?

Comment: Alternatively I could use a .copy() to copy the columns I want and then slice said new dataframe--but I'm trying to find a way to do this without altering the original master dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I don't personally like to use the `.plot` method of a `DataFrame`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plotter(df, cols, location):
  for col in cols:
    plt.plot(df[col].loc[location].values)
  plt.show()
```

This function just calls `plt.plot` using the underlying `numpy` array that holds your data, at `col` and `location` respectively.

As your needs change, you can alter this function to do whatever you want from `pyplot`, so you have a lot of control. No `.copy` or `.drop` or editing of the `df` is called for as far as I understand your problem.